# Eclipse IDE timestamps file incorrectly

Tags: php, eclipse

I am using Eclipse IDE 2021 03 to create PHP files. I am in the US Eastern time zone, and my remote server is in the Central time zone. However, the timestamps on the files I save are aligned with the Sydney, Australia time zone. How do I correct the Eclipse clock?

Comment: where is eclipse and what is timezone for OS on that machine?

Comment: If you want to have a different time zone in Eclipse than in your OS, add the following [Java time zone property](https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/setting-the-timezone-for-the-java-environment-841187402.html) as last line in `eclipse.ini`: `-Duser.timezone=America/New_York`